# How to compare Fraction with int?

Tags: java, comparison, fractions

I use apach commons library(`org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction`).

Now I compare `int` and `Fraction` object like this:

```
private static final int MAX_VALID_RATIO = 3;
....
fraction.compareTo(Fraction.getFraction(MAX_VALID_RATIO, 1))
```

It looks not nice.

`Fraction.getFraction(MAX_VALID_RATIO)` has only double builder.

Can you advise nicer way?

Comment: What do you mean by "It looks not nice"?

Comment: @Manuel S. from my side second argument 1 excessive

Answer (score 1):

You can just retrieve the [`intValue()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html#intValue%28%29) of the  `Fraction` and compare with your value:

> Gets the fraction as an `int`. This returns the whole number part of the fraction.

This method will return the value of the fraction truncated of the decimals. For example, the fraction `10 / 3` will have an `intValue()` of 3.

```
boolean greater = fraction.intValue() >= MAX_VALID_RATIO
```

Comment: it will return wrong result if my fraction would 3/1

Comment: @gstackoverflow Why? The `intValue()` would be 3 in this case. What result do you want?

Comment: 10/3 is invalid result for me but 9/3 is valid

Comment: @gstackoverflow Can you expand a little? How is it invalid? What would be the valid result?

Comment: 9/3 >3 - false;  10/3 > 3 - true

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, you need to use `>=` and not `>`.

Comment: your approach doesn't allow to distinguish10/3 and 9/3. intValue() always will return 3

Answer (score 0):

Comparing an integer to a fraction can be done best in 2 steps:

1. Get `fraction.intValue` and compare to your int. If your int is strictly greater or smaller than the fraction's `intValue()` you can stop here.
2. Otherwise get the fraction's deliminator and numerator and do: `deliminator % numerator`. If this results in 0, they are equal, otherwise the fraction is bigger.

Comment: You can put all of that in a seperate method, but yea, it's a matter of taste I suppose ;)